# Google Cloud Storage Client

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I make first steps with GCS

First, I created service account in my project and got keyfile in json

Next, I tried to write script like this [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python#google-cloud-storage)

But...

```
from gcloud import storage

client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/path/to/keyfile.json')

bucket = client.get_bucket('enggeo')
# Then do other things...
blob = bucket.get_blob('/ETicket.pdf')
print blob.download_as_string()
blob2 = bucket.blob('/wtt.txt')
blob2.upload_from_filename(filename='/home/test2/.www/test')
```

And getting error

```
File "tt.py", line 3, in <module>
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/path/to/keyfile.json')  # TODO: rel paths
File "/home/test2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/client.py", line 64, in from_service_account_json
return cls(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/test2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/storage/client.py", line 53, in __init__
http=http)
File "/home/test2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/client.py", line 181, in __init__
_ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project)
File "/home/test2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/client.py", line 146, in __init__
raise ValueError('Project was not passed and could not be '
```

Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/path/to/keyfile.json', 'project')

Need to specified args for JSONClient

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/gcloud-api.html#gcloud.client.JSONClient

Comment: The authentication overview documentation needs to be updated: [Gloud Authentication - Service Accounts](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/gcloud-auth.html#service-accounts)